# Meteor local package array returns empty on method call

Tags: meteor

I have a local package with the following code

```
@articleSubmitMethodCallbacks = []
articleSubmitMethodCallbacks.push(addThumbnailOnSubmit)
```

This works and returns an array with a function in.

Then I have a method called **articleInsert**

In that method I have the following code

```
article = articleSubmitMethodCallbacks.reduce(((result,currentFunction)->
 return currentFunction (result)
), article)
```

Now for some reason, every time I call this method, articleSubmitMethodCallbacks stays an empty array, even though before it ran it has the function in it. It somehow gets reset, any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Okay strange answer but here it goes, apparently it has something to do with the naming articleSubmitMethodCallbacks that interferes with something inside Meteor.

If I use any other array name, it works perfect. To be clear I didn't overwrite articleSubmitMethodCallbacks anywhere and in fact the code above was the only reference to it in the whole project.